# Where the script is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, path, include

it's a stupid question but I'm not sure...if I have an external js file that runs an ajax jquery call the url that I specified inside the file must be considered relative to the position of the js(fun.js) or the position where the parent file(index.html) is?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relative URL are always relative to the document, not the imported js files.

For most issues* you may consider your imported js files just as if they were included in your document at the point where you have the `script` element.

**There are differences regarding the loading time, `"use strict"` and the automatic statement closing at ends of file.*

Answer (score 0):

It's not matter where the js file located. It's matter which url you call through ajax.